# Sublime Text markdown files color scheme messed up

Tags: sublimetext3, markdown, text-editor, color-scheme

I use Sublime Text 3 as my primary text editor with the [Material Theme](https://github.com/equinusocio/material-theme). All my code looks generally like this:

[image: Material theme working fine]

The color scheme for all markdown files was also something similar to this. However, a few hours back all `.md` files got a weird color scheme and they look like this now:[image: Markdown files color scheme messed up]

I haven't installed any new package or plugin. This happened all of a sudden. What could be the problem?

Comment: Color scheme is a setting that can be applied on a syntax-specific basis, so that's a potential cause. You can do `Sublime Text > Preferences > Settings  - Syntax Specific` while you have a markdown file open to see if there's something like that in there. You can also open the Sublime console (`View > Show Console`) and enter `view.settings().get("color_scheme")` to see if the color scheme is the one you think it is.

Comment: Uh, your images aren't displaying... Oh sorry, imgur is down.

Answer (score 0):

You must have a plugin installed. It's possible you installed it before but it didn't apply to .md or didn't use new theme, then it got updated automatically and applied theme to your .md.

Use `package control: remove package` to check your plugins relate to markdown. like smartmarkdown, markdown extended, markdownedit etc.